# What is the use of public static keyword in main() method in Java?

Tags: static, program-entry-point, public, void

1. In the declaration of the main method:
   public static void main(String[] args){
   }
   which of the following statement is NOT correct:

a.  public keyword enables the JVM to access the main method

b.  static keyword allows a method to be called from outside a class without creating an 
instance of the class

c.  void keyword tells the compiler that the method will not return a value

d.  args is a string and store command line arguments

Comment: I think you should take the site [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first before asking this question, and show some work you've made on it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what they're thinking is *a*, because the JVM can access non-public methods. It has to, or it wouldn't be able to run them.